# AutoSizeColumns not working properly in ASP .NET Core with DoNetCore.NPOI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, npoi

I'm using **DoNetCore.NPOI** to export a **Grid (mvc6-grid)** into an **Excel** file. During the exporting process, I have set the property:

> Sheet.AutoSizeColumn(columnIndex)

for each column in my grid, but the resulting file shows that text in each column is being cutted.

Here you have an example about what I am saying:

**AutoSizeColumn Cutted Text Example:**

[image: AutoSizeColumn Cutted Text Example]

I have trying to change the font family, but it has not done anything.

I think that maybe could be important to inform you that in one column there could be specials characters like the "ñ" character.

Thank You!

Comment: I found your post, because I hit the same Problem as you! Unfortunatly, no answers for now, do you found a solution by yourself or elsewhere?